# How to add a column into a CSV and fill it depending on a specific value using terminal or Python

Tags: python, csv, terminal, multiple-columns

How do I add a new column called test in CSV using terminal or Python depending on Diagnosis columns?

PreProcess data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2v5Z.png)

```
        Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3  Diag_4
Patient1    1   0        202    1
Patient2    0   202         0   1
Patient3    1   1           1   1
Patient4    0   1           0   202
Patient5    0   1           1   0
Patient6    202 0           0   0
Patient7    1   1           1   1
```

I want the script to:

1- **Add a column called test**

2- go line by line

3- If **"202" is found**, it **deletes everything afterwards** and and set the **Test column** to **Yes**

4- If **"202" is not found**, nothing gets deleted, then **Test Column** is to be set to **No**

PostProcessed data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSvf2.png)

```
        Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3  Diag_4  Test
Patient1    1   0        202            Yes
Patient2    0   202                     Yes
Patient3    1   1          1    1       No
Patient4    0   1          0    202     Yes
Patient5    0   1          1    0        No
Patient6    202                          Yes
Patient7    1   1          1    1         No
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { print $0",Test" } NR>1&&/202/ { twootwo=0;printf "%s",$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="202") { printf ",%s",$i;twootwo=1 } else { if ( twootwo==1 ) { printf "," } else { printf ",%s",$i } } } printf ",%s\n","Yes" } NR>1&&!/202/ { print $0" No" } ' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { 
                 print $0",Test" # Where the record number is one, print the headers followed by , and Text
               } 
         NR>1&&/202/ { # Process lines that aren't the header and have a 202 entry
                 twootwo=0; # Initialise a variable for later use
                 printf "%s",$1; # Print the first field followed by ,
                 for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { # Loop through the rest of the fields
                   if ($i=="202") { 
                     printf ",%s",$i; # If the entry is 202, print
                     twootwo=1 # Also set the variable twootwo to 1
                   } 
                   else { 
                     if ( twootwo==1 ) { 
                       printf ","  # If twootwo is 1 (there is a 202 already seen in the record) print a blank field
                     } 
                     else { 
                       printf ",%s",$i # If 202 hasn't been seen, print the field
                     } 
                    } 
                  } 
                 printf ",%s\n","Yes" # Print the ending "Yes"
                 } 
    NR>1&&!/202/ { # When not the header record and where there are no 202 entries, print the line along with , and "No"
                   print $0",No" 
                 } ' file
```